# Combine separate spreadsheets into one master sheet in Excel?

Tags: database, excel, office-2013

I need to combine three excel spreadsheets into one "master" sheet quickly.

The first sheet has the following columns:

- Customer (Company Name)
- Email
- Telephone
- Fax
- Contact
- Contact's Telephone
- Contact's Fax
- Contact's Email

The second sheet has the following columns:

- Customer (Company Name)
- Delivery Street
- Delivery Country
- Delivery Zip

The last sheet has the following columns:

- Customer (Company Name)
- Sales Representative

I am tasked with combining the above information into one Excel sheet within the next few hours. Obviously if the customer lists were identical I would just copy columns and call it a day. But some sheets have duplicates, and in all three sheets the customers are not identical. I need a "master" set of the data with the following columns:

- Customer ID (auto-assign)
- Customer
- Sales Representative
- Contact
- Contact Email
- Contact Telephone
- Contact Fax
- Company Telephone
- Company Email
- Delivery Info

I have Excel 2013, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy the Customer (Company Name) lists to a single sheet and then perform a Remove Duplicates and use that for the 'Master' sheet column B.

The Customer ID would be a simply fill down, type 1 in cell A2 and then 2 in cell A3 and then select cells A2 and A3 and then double-click the lower-right corner of the selection to have it autofill down to the last company name in column B.

Then, rest would be appropriate VLOOKUP formulas.  For example, in cell sheet 'Master' C2 (Sales Representative), the formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2,'Sheet3'!$A:$B,2,FALSE),"")
```

And in sheet 'Master' cell D2 (Contact), the formula would be:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2,'Sheet1'!$A:$H,5,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: Thank you! I had the VLOOKUP's going, but my formula was incorrect. Big help!